# Shortening while loop with lots of if statements

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
while (something < something) {
        array2.clear();
        }
    }
```

How would I shorten this loop, it seems very repetitive, especially the first 4 if statements. Should I use a switch statement? If so, could you give me an example using one of my if statements.

Comment: Without knowing what this code suppose to do, how can you expect we can shorten it.

Comment: Well, `if (y - 1 >= 0 && cells[x][y - 1].checkWalls() == true) {` could always be shortened to `if (y - 1 >= 0 && cells[x][y - 1].checkWalls()) {`.  There's no need to compare it to true.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a loop with an enum

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH(0, +1), SOUTH(0, -1), EAST(+1, 0), WEST(-1, 0);
    public final int x, y;
    Direction(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}
```

Then you can loop them in a random order

```
List<Direction> dirs = Arrays.asList(Direction.values());
while (visitedCells < totalCells) {
    Collection.shuffle(dirs);
    boolean found = false;
    for (Direction dir : dirs) {
       int x2 = x + dir.x;
       int y2 = y + dir.y;
       if (0 <= x2 && x2 < sizeX && 0 <= y2 && y2 < sizeT && cells[x2][y2].checkWalls()) {

           visitedCells++;
           found = true;
           break;
       }
    }
    if (!found) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're changing the behavior by doing it that way.

Comment: And you're going to still end up with a bunch of if statements trying to figure out WHICH of the walls was hit inside your `if (!found)` (because what values need to be set is slightly different for each of them).  Sorry, I just don't like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to use a switch statement in this situation.  This might not be popular, but I'd leave it mostly as-is.  Yes, there is some repetition, and that's not ideal, but it doesn't seem to be enough to be worth refactoring, especially considering the subtle differences in what you're doing inside each of the if statements and the possibility that more than one if statement - or none of them - could trigger.  Attempts to stuff this into a function that you could call 4 times, or something, would be possible to do, but it would either just move the problem to the function, or it would make the code less readable to what I feel is an unacceptable degree.

There is one thing I see you could safely shorten.

```
if (y - 1 >= 0 && cells[x][y - 1].checkWalls() == true) {
```

could be shortened to

```
if (y - 1 >= 0 && cells[x][y - 1].checkWalls()) {
```

and the similar lines shortened similarly.  (`true == true` will always be `true` and `false == true` will always be `false` so comparing a boolean expression to `true` doesn't do anything.)

Each `hV = new VHelper();` could probably be put inside the if statement it precedes.  You don't need to make the object unless you're setting its values, right?  This won't shorten the code, but it will prevent your code from making a few unnecessary objects, improving efficiency slightly.

Also, the line starting `if (x + 1 < sizeY` looks like a typo - you're comparing an x value to sizeY, which I'm guessing was not intentional.  (And I realize that subtle typos like this are the exact reason you want to refactor - but there's simply no getting around the fact that you have to check x against sizeX and y against sizeY, no matter how you arrange your code.)